# How to dispatch actions from Child components three level down?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I am currently facing this issue designing a React application and I don't seem to be able to find an answer to it.

So my application has following heirarchy of Components in React Router

App
-> DynamicContainer
-> -> LoginComponent

Now, LoginComponents has form elements to take username and password.

I have userActionCreators where the login is handled, and it dispatches login successful when finished, but I don't seem to be able find the right way to connect my LoginComponent to dispatch actions or call actionCreators.

How do I do it? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One option is to bind your single-purpose forms to their actions with `connect`. Since `<LoginComponent />` is typically always doing the exact same thing, you can use it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as userActionCreators from '../actions/users';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
   static propTypes = {
     login: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
   }

   render() { 
     const { login } = this.props;
     const { username, password } = this.state;

     return (
       <form onSubmit={ () => login(username, password) }>
         ...
       </form>
     );
   }
}

export default connect(null, userActionCreators)(LoginComponent);
```

`connect` automatically binds the action creator and separately provides `dispatch` to `props`, so if you want to be more explicit, the above example is the same as

```
import React from 'react';
import { login } from '../actions/users';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
   static propTypes = {
     dispatch: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
   }

   render() { 
     const { login, dispatch } = this.props;
     const { username, password } = this.state;

     return (
       <form onSubmit={ () => dispatch(login(username, password)) }>
         ...
       </form>
     );
   }
}

export default connect()(LoginComponent);
```

And for reference, `userActionCreators`:

```
const LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'LOGIN_SUCCESS';
const LOGIN_FAILED = 'LOGIN_FAILED';

export function login(username, password) {
  if (username === 'realUser' && password === 'secretPassword') {
    return { type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: { name: 'Joe', username: 'realUser' } };
  } else {
    return { type: LOGIN_FAILED, error: 'Invalid username or password };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you add to answer how `userActionCreators` should look like?

Comment: I added `userActionsCreators` example and expanded on `connect`

Comment: Thanks for help, in the middle code block you forgot to extract `dispatch` from `this.props`.

Answer (score 7):

if I understood you correctly, if you read [Example: Todo List | Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) you'll find the example that you might be looking for.

There's the **App** component, *connect()ed* to Redux, and then there're the other components: **AddTodo**, **TodoList**, **Todo** and **Footer**.

**App** calls **TodoList** that calls **Todo** where user can click something.  This click will surf back callback after callback, from **Todo** to **TodoList** to **App** as detailed below:

1. **App** calls **TodoList** with
   `<TodoList todos={visibleTodos} onTodoClick={ index => dispatch(completeTodo(index)) } />`
2. **TodoList** calls **Todo** with
   `<Todo {...todo} key={index} onClick={ () => this.props.onTodoClick(index) } />`
3. **Todo** component has a `<li>` with `onClick={this.props.onClick}` property.

So, backwards, when someones clicks inside the **Todo** compoment, that will call `this.props.onClick` which will call `this.props.onTodoClick(index)` from **TodoList** (notice the optional added parameter *index*), then, at last, this will invoke the function `dispatch(completeTodo(index))` from **App**.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Pass a bound actionCreator from your Container (which is connected to Redux) down to a child component (which is not connected to Redux) via the `props` object.
2. Consider adopting [React Component Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) in your project.

Comment: How can I pass boundActionCreator when the heirarchy is defined by react-router where a different child component is attached to DynamicContainer Component which acts as a place holder. I just have {this.props.children} inside DynamicContainer Component.

Comment: So you are trying to pass action creators from the root of your application through react router into a login form component of some sort?